# migrating app from upstart to systemctl failing with 'dead'

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

new to this area, and trying to setup this project on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

https://github.com/thoukydides/heatmiser-wifi

the project is no longer maintained, but the instructions talk about using upstart to register a daemon. I understand that upstart is deprecated and is replaced by systemctl. I have setup a systemctl file as below based on the current upstart file.

> [Unit] Description=HeatmiserDaemon After=mysql.service
>
> [Service] ExecStart=/usr/bin/perl /usr/local/bin/heatmiser_daemon
>
> [Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target

I have saved this to /etc/systemd/system/heatmiser-daemon.service, and am able to register the service and start it. Checking its status shows the following:

> heatmiser-daemon.service - HeatmiserDaemon Loaded: loaded
> (/etc/systemd/system/heatmiser-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset:
> enabled) Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2023-11-19 15:41:40 UTC;
> 15s ago Process: 2213 ExecStart=/usr/bin/perl
> /usr/local/bin/heatmiser_daemon (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) Main
> PID: 2213 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

However, upon querying the running services, it is not shown. It is shown when I run systemctl --type=service --state=dead as below:

> heatmiser-daemon.service loaded inactive dead HeatmiserDaemon

So it seems to me that the service is running and calling the related .pl file, but it seems to be exiting prematurely.

I'm at a point where I'm not sure how to troubleshoot further, so asking for suggestions on if there are any log files etc that can help me to see what the daemon is doing. The app log file doesn't give any help either at this point.

Any suggestions or pointers welcome.

thanks

Comment: Did you perform the preliminary database setup as described [here](https://github.com/thoukydides/heatmiser-wifi/wiki/InstallationWebInterface#logging-to-a-database)?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, the heatmiser database has been created, and I've confirmed that. I can see that the tables that are created in that database by the daemon, have not been created though, which I understand is the job of the daemon. This tallies with the daemon exiting. The logging on the app itself isn't very detailed, and the logs literally only tell me that the daemon has run, but not much else.

Comment: Please learn how to paste the systemd unit files correctly (edit your question)